# My website keeps saying "cannot find file or directory"!

Tags: html, css, directory, find

I'm trying to create a website where you can watch live streams. But when I try to watch the stream on my website, it doesn't work. It keeps saying "Can not find file or directory" (Translated from Dutch). I'm new with HTML so please mind my stupidness.

I can't post my CSS because it's too large

Console

live-cricket-online-1.htm:229 GET file:///C:/Users/Sukbir/Desktop/crichd/votebox.htm net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
live-cricket-online-1.htm:247 GET file:///C:/Users/Sukbir/Desktop/crichd/frame.htm net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
live-cricket-online-1.htm:275 GET file:///C:/Users/Sukbir/Desktop/crichd/upcoming-cricket-matches.htm net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
post-widget.js:22 GET file://po.st/v1/status?pubKey=m161gi02avu6f33ffqrh&1461664496450&callback=r1PoStJSONP7581 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDc.appendTo @ post-widget.js:22c.loadScript @ post-widget.js:23fetch @ post-widget.js:81h.fetchStatus @ post-widget.js:106t.WidgetClass.c.defineClass._fetchStatus @ post-widget.js:188(anonymous function) @ post-widget.js:188

HTML of the page

```
<html class=" pw-locale-en ra1-pw-desktop" id="HTML_1"><head id="HEAD_2">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" id="META_3">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" id="META_4">
<title id="TITLE_5">Live Cricket Streaming - Live Cricket - Watch Cricket Online - Free</title>
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Live Cricket Streaming, Watch World Cup Twenty20 2016, Live Cricket Streaming of World Cup 2016" id="META_6">
<meta name="KEYWORDS" content="live cricket streaming, live cricket, watch cricket streaming, watch live cricket, watch free cricket, free cricket" id="META_7">
<style type="text/css" id="STYLE_8"></style><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://i.po.st/static/v3/css/r1post.css?4_9_1_pch_945" media="all" id="LINK_9"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://i.po.st/static/v3/css/share2quote.css" media="all" id="LINK_10"></head>

<body link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000" id="BODY_11">

<div align="center" id="DIV_12">
  <center id="CENTER_13">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="939" id="TABLE_14" height="1120">
    <tbody id="TBODY_15"><tr id="TR_16">
      <td width="764" valign="top" height="1120" id="TD_17">
      <div align="center" id="DIV_18">
        <center id="CENTER_19">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="TABLE_20" height="73">
          <tbody id="TBODY_21"><tr id="TR_22">
            <td width="22%" height="73" id="TD_23">
            <img border="0" src="http://www.crictime.com/files/cricket.gif" alt="Watch Live Cricket" width="199" height="63" id="IMG_24"></td>
            <td width="78%" height="73" id="TD_25">
            <p align="left" id="P_26">

          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcricket.we.lv.u&amp;width=220&amp;height=62&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:220px; height:62px;" allowtransparency="true" name="I44" id="IFRAME_27"></iframe>

          </p></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </center> 
      </div>
      <div align="center" id="DIV_28">
        <center id="CENTER_29">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="TABLE_30" height="23">
          <tbody id="TBODY_31"><tr id="TR_32">
            <td width="14%" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" align="center" height="20" id="TD_33"><b id="B_34">
            <font face="Verdana" id="FONT_35">
            <a style="text-decoration: none" href="index.htm" id="A_36">
            <font color="#000000" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_37">Home</font></a></font></b></td>
            <td width="14%" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" align="center" height="20" id="TD_38"><b id="B_39">
            <font face="Verdana" id="FONT_40">
            <a href="cricket-schedules.htm" style="text-decoration: none" id="A_41">
            <font color="#000000" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_42">Schedule</font></a></font></b></td>
            <td width="14%" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" align="center" height="20" id="TD_43"><b id="B_44">
            <font face="Verdana" id="FONT_45">
            <a href="cricket-results.htm" style="text-decoration: none" id="A_46">
            <font color="#000000" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_47">Results</font></a></font></b></td>
            <td width="14%" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" align="center" height="20" id="TD_48"><b id="B_49">
            <font face="Verdana" id="FONT_50">
            <a style="text-decoration: none" href="live-score.htm" id="A_51">
            <font color="#000000" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_52">Score Card</font></a></font></b></td>
            <td width="14%" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" align="center" height="20" id="TD_53"><b id="B_54">
            <font color="#000000" face="Verdana" size="2" id="FONT_55">
            <a style="text-decoration: none" href="cricket-icc-rankings.htm" id="A_56">ICC 
            Rankings</a></font></b></td>
            <td width="15%" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" align="center" height="20" id="TD_57"><b id="B_58">
            <font color="#000000" face="Verdana" size="2" id="FONT_59">
            <a style="text-decoration: none" href="post-feedback.htm" id="A_60">Feedback</a></font></b></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div align="center" id="DIV_61">
        <center id="CENTER_62">
        <table style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" id="TABLE_63" border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#c0c0c0" cellpadding="0" width="99%" height="15">
          <tbody id="TBODY_64"><tr id="TR_65">
            <td bgcolor="#ecedd8" width="20%" height="15" id="TD_66">
            <p align="right" id="P_67"><b id="B_68">
            <font color="#008000" face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_69">
            LIVE STREAMING</font></b></p></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffcc00" width="5%" align="middle" height="15" id="TD_70"><b id="B_71">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_72">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-1.htm" id="A_73">SERVER 1</a></font></b></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffcc00" width="5%" align="middle" height="15" id="TD_74"><b id="B_75">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_76">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-2.htm" id="A_77">SERVER 2</a></font></b></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffcc00" width="5%" align="middle" height="15" id="TD_78"><b id="B_79">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_80">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-3.htm" id="A_81">SERVER 3</a></font></b></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffcc00" width="5%" align="middle" height="15" id="TD_82"><b id="B_83">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_84">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-4.htm" id="A_85">SERVER 4</a></font></b></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </center>
      </div> 
      <div align="center" id="DIV_86">
        <center id="CENTER_87">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="TABLE_88" height="200">
          <tbody id="TBODY_89"><tr id="TR_90">
            <td width="50%" height="265" align="center" id="TD_91">










<iframe src="http://www.crictime.com/files/300x250-ad.htm" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" width="300" height="250" name="I55" id="IFRAME_92"></iframe>                </td>
            <td width="50%" height="200" align="center" id="TD_93">












<!-- BEGIN IFRAME TAG - [* Crictime [C.O.M]] - 300x250 < - DO NOT MODIFY -->






<iframe src="http://www.crictime.com/files/300x250-ad.htm" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" width="300" height="250" name="I57" id="IFRAME_94"></iframe>                
<!-- END TAG --></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div align="center" id="DIV_95">
        <center id="CENTER_96">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="TABLE_97" height="44">
          <tbody id="TBODY_98"><tr id="TR_99">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="8" id="TD_100">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_101">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="1" id="TD_102">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_103">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="1" id="TD_104">
      <p align="center" id="P_105"><b id="B_106"><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 13pt" id="FONT_107">
      Live 
      Cricket Streaming Online - Watch Live Cricket</font></b></p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_108">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="6" id="TD_109">
                <p align="center" id="P_110">
            <span style="font-weight: 700" id="SPAN_111">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_112">Video</font></span><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: 700" id="FONT_113">
            may take some time to load</font></p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_114">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="27" id="TD_115">
            <p align="center" id="P_116"><span style="font-weight: 700" id="SPAN_117">
            <font color="#008000" face="Verdana" style="font-size: 11pt" id="FONT_118">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://livelovesms.com/" id="A_119">
            <font color="#008000" id="FONT_120">Send Free SMS to Pakistan</font></a> |
            <a target="_blank" href="http://smsdraft.com" id="A_121"><font color="#008000" id="FONT_122">
            Good Morning SMS</font></a></font></span></p></td>
          </tr>



    <!--

          <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="38">
            <p dir="ltr">
            <span style="font-weight: 700">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 12pt">
            <a target="_top" href="live-cricket-online-7.htm">
            <font color="#0000FF">Click Here</font></a> to Watch </font>
            <font face="Verdana">Pakistan V South Africa</font></span></td>
          </tr>







          <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="27">
            <p dir="ltr">
            <span style="font-weight: 700">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 13pt">
            <a target="_top" href="live-cricket-online-15.htm">
            <font color="#0000FF">Click Here</font></a> to Watch Masters Champions League</font></span></td>
          </tr>







   <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="27">
            <span style="font-weight: 700">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 13pt">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-13.htm">
            <font color="#0000FF">Click Here</font></a> to Watch Pakistan Super League</font></span></td>
          </tr>







          <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="27">
            <p>
            <span style="font-weight: 700">
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 13pt; font-weight:700">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-7.htm"><font color="#0000FF">Click Here</font></a></font><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 12pt">
            </font>
            <font face="Verdana"><span style="font-size: 13pt">to Watch </span></font>
            <font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 13pt">Australia Vs South Africa</font></span></td>
          </tr>

      -->

          <tr id="TR_123">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="27" id="TD_124">
            <iframe name="I64" src="votebox.htm" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" height="73" width="471" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0" id="IFRAME_125">
            Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe></td>          </tr>



          <tr id="TR_126">
            <td width="100%" align="center" height="46" id="TD_127">
            <font face="Verdana" size="2" id="FONT_128">Share this page <div class="pw pw-widget ra1-pw-classicWidget ra1-pw_size_medium pw-layout-horizontal pw-counter-horizontal" id="DIV_129">          
    <a class="pw-button pw-button-facebook button-type-square pw-size-medium" id="A_130"><span class="pw-icon ra1-pw-icon ra1-pw-icon-facebook" id="SPAN_131"></span></a>           
    <a class="pw-button pw-button-twitter button-type-square pw-size-medium" id="A_132"><span class="pw-icon ra1-pw-icon ra1-pw-icon-twitter" id="SPAN_133"></span></a>         
    <a class="pw-button pw-button-email button-type-square pw-size-medium" id="A_134"><span class="pw-icon ra1-pw-icon ra1-pw-icon-email" id="SPAN_135"></span></a>         
    <a class="pw-button pw-button-post button-type-square pw-size-medium pw-button-counter-horizontal" aria-haspopup="true" id="A_136"><span class="pw-icon ra1-pw-icon ra1-pw-icon-post" id="SPAN_137"></span><span class="pw-button-counter" id="SPAN_138"><i class="pw-button-counter__brd" id="I_139"></i><span class="pw-button-counter__count ra1-pw-button-counter-value" id="SPAN_140">1.7K</span></span></a>       
</div>
<script async="" src="//cdn.spoutable.com/71eea6a0-3c06-4410-9400-a683c553f442/spoutable.js" id="SCRIPT_141"></script><script src="http://i.po.st/share/script/post-widget.js#publisherKey=m161gi02avu6f33ffqrh" type="text/javascript" id="SCRIPT_142"></script></font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_143">

            <td width="100%" height="43" align="center" id="TD_144">
                <iframe src="frame.htm" height="467" width="595" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0" name="I17" id="IFRAME_145"></iframe>

            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_146">

            <td width="100%" height="31" align="center" id="TD_147">
            <p align="center" id="P_148"><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 13pt" id="FONT_149">Any Problem? 
      Watch On <b id="B_150">
            <font color="#000000" id="FONT_151">
            <a href="live-cricket-online-2.htm" id="A_152">Server 2</a></font></b></font></p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_153">

            <td width="100%" height="33" align="center" id="TD_154">
            <span style="font-weight: 700" id="SPAN_155"><font face="Verdana" id="FONT_156">
            <span style="font-size: 13pt" id="SPAN_157">Crictime.Com can also be accessed by
            Crictime.Be</span></font></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_158">

            <td width="100%" height="9" align="center" id="TD_159">
            <span style="font-weight: 700; background-color: #FFCC00" id="SPAN_160">
            <font face="Verdana" id="FONT_161">Upcoming Cricket Matches</font></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_162">

            <td width="100%" height="9" align="center" id="TD_163">
            <iframe name="I2" src="upcoming-cricket-matches.htm" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" height="222" width="668" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0" id="IFRAME_164">
            Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_165">

            <td width="100%" height="1" align="center" id="TD_166">
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div align="center" id="DIV_167">
        <center id="CENTER_168">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="TABLE_169" height="10">
          <tbody id="TBODY_170"><tr id="TR_171">
            <td width="100%" height="1" id="TD_172"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_173">
            <td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#A5CFDC" id="TD_174">
            <p align="right" id="P_175"><font face="Verdana" id="FONT_176"><b id="B_177">
            <font style="font-size: 10pt" id="FONT_178"><font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#A5CFDC" id="FONT_179">  <script type="text/javascript" src="" id="SCRIPT_180"></script>   </font>&nbsp; 
            <a href="post-feedback.htm" id="A_181">Feedback</a>&nbsp; 
            | <a href="privacy-policy.htm" id="A_182">Privacy Policy</a></font><span style="font-size: 10pt" id="SPAN_183">| </span></b>
            <span style="font-size: 10pt" id="SPAN_184">Crictime.Com</span></font></p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="TR_185">
            <td width="100%" height="1" id="TD_186"></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </center>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td width="174" align="center" valign="top" height="1120" id="TD_187">


<div align="center" id="DIV_188">
  <center id="CENTER_189">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="TABLE_190" height="1241">
    <tbody id="TBODY_191"><tr id="TR_192">
      <td height="641" id="TD_193">


<p align="center" id="P_194"><!-- BEGIN STANDARD TAG - 160 x 600 - ROS: 1 - DO NOT MODIFY -->


<iframe src="http://www.crictime.com/files/160x600-ad.htm" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" width="160" height="600" name="I63" id="IFRAME_195"></iframe>    
      </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="TR_196">
      <td height="600" id="TD_197">



    <p align="center" id="P_198">




<iframe src="http://www.crictime.com/files/160x600-ad.htm" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" width="160" height="600" name="I63" id="IFRAME_199"></iframe>    
        </p><p align="center" id="P_200">


&nbsp;</p></td>



    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  </center>
</div>






<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.liveadexchanger.com/a/display.php?r=390124" id="SCRIPT_201"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="SCRIPT_202">
(function(){
  var spoutjs=document.createElement('script'),firstjs=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  spoutjs.async=1;
  spoutjs.src='//cdn.spoutable.com/71eea6a0-3c06-4410-9400-a683c553f442/spoutable.js';
  firstjs.parentNode.insertBefore(spoutjs,firstjs)
})();
</script>





<script type="text/javascript" id="SCRIPT_203">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      </script><script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript" id="SCRIPT_204"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="SCRIPT_205">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-2414894-6");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>






</td></tr></tbody></table></center></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Please get rid of the messy code. Use stylesheets instead of inline css. No need for tables...

Comment: then y don't you use jsfiddle to show your code..it will be easy to understand

Comment: Also, can you post what the console says in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

This Url you given in iframe  is not working please check

```
 http://www.crictime.com/files/160x600-ad.htm
```

use working url